# How to use setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make my flutter bottom navigation bar to work and navigate to different screen based on the list but not sure why I'm getting an error on setState.

I think I might have to use StatefullWidget to use setState but I'm just wondering is there a work around to make it work.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

I have tried using useState but It's not working either.

```dart
class Dashboard2 extends HookWidget {
  const Dashboard2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final color = useProvider(colorProvider);
    int _pageIndex = 0;


    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: navigation.elementAt(_pageIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: DotNavigationBar(
          onTap: (int index) {

        setState(() {
                      _pageIndex = index;
                    });
    
          },

        )

final List<Widget> navigation = [
  Home(),
  Schedule(),
  SmallGroup(),
  SpeakerInfo()
];
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? could you please tell me if HookWidget is Stateful? also please note that in order to use `setState((){});` you need to have a `Stateful` widget Or by using 'StatefulBuilder()'

Answer (score 1):

Define `int _pageIndex = 0;` outside of build!

Problem that when you tap on NavigationBar _pageIndex updated and then setState(){} is executed and it set _pageIndex as 0 again each time!